# SQL Identify if a 30 day break occurs in a date

Tags: sql

I have a table that I'm trying to identify how many accounts were re-activated in the past year using SQL. For example, once an account goes inactive for 30-days (no purchases), the account is considered inactive. So I want to find accounts that have a 30-day break, but subsequently later in the year there is a purchase.

Here is the table I'm working with:

```
account_id | purchase_date | unique_purchase_id
```

Here is what I have so far. I'm assuming we will need to use a partition, but not sure the next step.

```
SELECT distinct 
    account_id,
    unique_purchase_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY purchase_date) AS test
FROM 
    purchase_table
```

Comment: Hi - try using LEAD/LAG on the purchase date and then checking if there is a gap of more than 30 days between the current record’s purchase date and the lead/lag purchase date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    WITH ranked_purchases AS (
    SELECT
        account_id,
        purchase_date,
        unique_purchase_id,
        LAG(purchase_date) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY purchase_date) AS 
    prev_purchase_date
    FROM 
        purchase_table
)
SELECT 
    account_id,
    unique_purchase_id
FROM 
    ranked_purchases
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(day, prev_purchase_date, purchase_date) >= 30
```

This query uses the LAG() window function to get the previous purchase date for each row within the same account. Then, it calculates the difference between the current purchase date and the previous one. If this difference is at least 30 days, it means there was a gap, indicating a potential re-activation.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use the window function `lag()` to get the interval between dates for a given account. The result can be filtered to get the interval larger than 30 days.

```
create table purchase_table(account_id int, purchase_date datetime, unique_purchase_id serial,primary key(unique_purchase_id) );

insert into purchase_table values
(1,'2023-01-02 10:00:01',default),
(1,'2023-01-04 10:00:01',default),
(1,'2023-02-02 10:00:01',default),
(1,'2023-02-03 10:00:01',default),
(2,'2023-01-03 10:00:01',default),
(2,'2023-03-02 10:00:01',default),
(2,'2023-04-15 10:00:01',default),
(3,'2023-09-03 10:00:01',default),
(3,'2023-09-04 10:00:01',default),
(3,'2023-10-15 10:00:01',default),
(4,'2023-12-03 10:00:01',default),
(4,'2024-01-13 10:00:01',default)
;

select account_id,purchase_date,intrv 
from (select account_id,purchase_date,
     to_days(purchase_date) - lag(to_days(purchase_date)) over(partition by account_id order by purchase_date) intrv
     from purchase_table
     where  purchase_date between '2023-01-01 00:00:01' and '2023-12-31 23:59:59') t 
where intrv>=30
;

-- result set:
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| account_id | purchase_date       | intrv |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
|          2 | 2023-03-02 10:00:01 |    58 |
|          2 | 2023-04-15 10:00:01 |    44 |
|          3 | 2023-10-15 10:00:01 |    41 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
```